# How do I keep the spacevim search results window open after opening a file?

Tags: search, spacevim

How can I keep the search results location list window open after opening a file in a new buffer?

Comment: Split the window? Idk spacevim though

Answer (score 2):

SpaceVim provides new key binding for async searching. it is  SPC s  J, the  result will  be put into quickfix list.

Answer (score 0):

The results get added to the QuickFix window. Without changing the leader character, which is set to `\`, you can use the following key sequences to show and navigate through the searches:

```
<Leader> q l    Open quickfix list window
<Leader> q c    clear quickfix list
<Leader> q n    jump to next item in quickfix list
<Leader> q p    jump to previous item in quickfix list
```

Opening the quickfix window should provide you with a the list of search results, but if you use the navigation key sequences, you can jump between the matches very quickly.

For me, the quickfix window appears underneath the NERDTree window, which makes it very small. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not but you might want to watch out for it.

Taken from this section of the [SpaceVim documentation](https://spacevim.org/documentation/#replread-eval-print-loop)